# Python Request: how to give cookie consent to server?

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some data of a website using python request. I have to login to the website though first. So I found the /acounts/login/ url and when i try to post to this URL with a payload containing my username and password I get redirected to a page where I have to give consent to cookies by pressing a big green button.. How can I do this with python request? Even when I just do s.get and print the url it is already redirected to this Cookie Consent Page..

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
res = s.get('https://example.nl/accounts/login/')
print(res.url)
```

When I inspect this cookie consent page I find the following relevant lines of HTML:

```
<form action="/consent?token=f1ad267c-377b-486a-b286-67ff63e3b046" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="permissions" value="functional">
                            <input type="hidden" name="permissions" value="analytics">
                            <input type="hidden" name="permissions" value="socialMedia">
                            <input type="hidden" name="permissions" value="advertising">
                            <input type="hidden" name="permissions" value="personalization">

                    <input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="">

                    <div class="buttons">
                        <input type="submit" data-track-click="{&quot;contentInteractionName&quot;: &quot;consentChange&quot;,&quot;cookiewallInitiator&quot;:&quot;f1tm&quot;,&quot;consentChoice&quot;: {&quot;permissions&quot;: { &quot;advertising&quot; : true,&quot;analytics&quot;: true,&quot;functional&quot;: true,&quot;personalization&quot;: true,&quot;socialMedia&quot;: true},&quot;consentScreen&quot;: &quot;front&quot;}}" value="Ja, ik ga akkoord" data-track-click-has-click-listener="true">
                        <a href="#" onclick="showAdvancedView()">Voorkeuren beheren</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I don't know what to do with this.. I would like to "press" the submit button to continue to the login page..

Comment: Can you share the actual url?

Comment: Login url: https://www.f1tm.nl/accounts/login/

redirected to: https://toestemming.ndcmediagroep.nl/?token=a86967d5-bcb8-403f-9063-86e1c1cff857

Comment: have you tried adding a header?

Comment: Yes I have.. makes no difference.. for example:

`myheader = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}`

`s = requests.Session()`

`res = s.get("https://www.f1tm.nl/accounts/login/", headers=myheader)`

`print(res1.url)`

This will print again the toestemmingen.ndcmedia url.. I tried posting to thus new url.. but im not sure what I'm supposted to post..